# Object reference not set to an instance of an object? Search result pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net

How should this code be written? I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object on ***if (!query.Keys[i].Contains("ddl"))***

```
string getLink(int toPage)
{
    NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
    query["p"] = toPage.ToString();

    string url = Request.Path;
    int count = query.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (!query.Keys[i].Contains("ddl"))
            url += string.Format("{0}{1}={2}",
                i == 0 ? "?" : "&",
                query.Keys[i],
                query.Keys[i] == "category" ? string.Join("TTT", query.GetValues(i)).Replace(" ", "+") : string.Join(",", query.GetValues(i)));
    }
```

Comment: CHECK FOR NULL. ALWAYS.

Comment: Something like `if (query.Keys.Contains(i) && !query.Keys[i].Contains("ddl"))` ?

Comment: Where are you setting the value for `count`? And where does `query` come from?

Comment: @Yuck string getLink(int toPage)
    {
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
        query["p"] = toPage.ToString();

        string url = Request.Path;
        int count = query.Count;

Answer (score 2):

As said, check for nulls. The following is an extreme check but it's better to be safe than sorry.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (query != null &&
        query.Keys != null &&
        i < query.Keys.Count &&
        query.ContainsKey(i) &&
        query.Keys[i] != null &&
        query.GetValues(i) != null &&
        !query.Keys[i].Contains("ddl"))  {
            url += string.Format(
                "{0}{1}={2}",
                i == 0 ? "?" : "&",
                query.Keys[i],
                query.Keys[i] == "category" ? string.Join("TTT", query.GetValues(i)).Replace(" ", "+") : string.Join(",", query.GetValues(i)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can rewrite it as

```
if (query!=null && query.ContainsKey(i) && !query.Keys[i].Contains("ddl"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug your application; set a breakpoint in the line that causes the exception.

- Check on the *first* iteration if query is null.
- Check on *each* iteration if query.Keys[i] is null

In debug mode, you can also check on what iteration the problem happens (already i==0 or later?). Otherwise, it's hard to tell without knowing what is going on.

I also don't know how you expect that anybody else than you will be able to maintain the code below the if-statement in two years... Simplifying it could make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but it sure looks like you could simply rewrite your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < query.Count-1; i++)
{



}
```

depending on the purpose of `count`.  You are most likely getting your error due to going past the length of your dictionary.  This would fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there maybe a problem with initialization

```
  NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
```

There maybe something wrong with

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query)
```

part of the code.